# YAML errors in semantics

Tags: google-app-engine

I have several (independent) questions if you can inform me. about Google Cloud App Engine

1) I would like to know if it was way, once again, with the command, that the application is deployed, can I remove from the "far"?
Do I delete a file locally; and that I do the command with the application gcloud to deploy, the file meets up to date or is automatically removed from the remote?
If "no", how could I remove from "remote"?

2) What you have already sent to the server, can I recover? Do kind do the reverse command to deploy the application?

3) I did not quite understand the difference between the static_files and upload exactly all that in the managers: of the file YAML. I saw in the documentation but after reading I did not understand everything. static_files, the directory followed by \ 1 and in the download, the full path with regular expression, is that it?
Yes but suddenly, if I want to include all subfolders with static_files, can I?
Kind that
static_files: / res / js / \ 1
includes
/res/js/toto/sousdossier/fichier.html

Comment: *"I have several (independent) questions"* - but you have asked them in a single question. Please don't do that. Also none of them really make sense; [tag:cloud] covers a lot of ground (sky?), are you asking about some specific technology?

Comment: Yes, App Engine